# Django upload and download files in google drive using googledriveapi

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

I am new to django and trying to create a web app to upload and download files to the google drive using gdriveapi.
I have gone through the python quickstart for Google drive and tried the code in manage.py where it is working.

How to write the same code to obtain credentials and upload and download in the django app?
How to write the view and model in django to obtain credentials and upload files to gdrive?

Comment: Create a form (?) Then process those details inside your API code

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include the exact issue you are having limit it to a single issue.  Include your code ([example]) and describe any errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for my model field I use `file = models.FileField(upload_to='todo', storage=gd_storage, blank=True, null=True)`, where todo is the app name. For the view I simply used the generic ModelViewSet, where you can just `serializer.save(file=self.request.data['file'])`